# I have problem with Modal Box for webstore

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I plan to open a game server and currently programming a store. What I want is a basic popup window (modal box) when a player click "purchase" it is gonna open a window where its says details and 3 buttons (Pay with paypal, pay with card , pay with wallet (Login required)). The only problem is that when I try to open a window for 1 item its shows some text (im doing for test now) but when I add other item its not poping out. I tried to fix it but its just not working and servers open in 3 weeks and that is only thing I need it. If any additional code is require I will provide to you. ALSO my point is to make few buttons to 1 popup with diffrent information (according to name(NAZWA), price(CENA) , desciption(OPIS))
MY CODE:

```
echo "<div class='usg'>";
                    echo "<p class='usg1'><img src='{$usg['img']}' width='75px; height: 75px;'</img></p> <br><br><br>";
                    echo "<p class='usg2'>".$usg['nazwa']."</p>";
                    echo "<p class='usg3'>".$usg['opis']."</p>";
                    echo "<p class='usg4'>".$usg['cena']."</p>";
                    echo "<button class='myBtn'>KUP</button>";
                echo "</div>";
                    }
                }
                $conn->close();
        
        ?>
    </div>
    <!-- The Modal -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">

      <!-- Modal content -->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <p>Some text the Modal..</p>
      </div>

    </div>

    <script>
    // Get the modal
    var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

    // Get the button that opens the modal
    var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn")[0-1];

    // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

    // When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
    btn.onclick = function() {
      modal.style.display = "block";
    }

    // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
    span.onclick = function() {
      modal.style.display = "none";
    }

    // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
    window.onclick = function(event) {
      if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
      }
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: This doesn't look like legal javascript var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn")[0-1]; try to use var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn"); Also please check out bootstrap modal https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp

Comment: can you help me make it so multiple buttons open 1 popup with diffrent information from database?

Comment: https://web.cortland.edu/flteach/mm-course/glossPopupDiv.html